# Use current date as tag?

Tags: tags, date

I want to make a simple calendar in my wordpress. I want to show every day different posts, which have the current date as tag.

For example, I put a tag 17-01-2017 in three posts. I want to get them as a list on 17-01-2017.

I have the following code, which works fine -

```
<?php 
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=something' );
?>
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
</ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, I can't change the preset value "something" to show current date like 17-01-2017. Can you please, help me?

Answer (score 2):

We can use e.g. [`current_time( 'd-m-y' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) to get the formatted current date. So you could try:

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( [ 'tag' => current_time( 'd-m-Y' ) ] );
```

Also note the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) parameter, if you want to target the post date part instead.

Comment: You might also want to adjust the `posts_per_page` parameter of `WP_Query`. Hope it helps.  @alexbg89

Comment: @alexbg89 Just as an addition. Should you opt to use `date_query`, make sure to add `future` to the retrievable `post_status` types.